# Componentwillunmount is called on render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a firebase database for react-native. My Main Component has a list of friends the user has added. when I go on to the main screen I bring add friends added to firebase database.

```js
 getUser = async useremail => {
    let ref = await firebase.database().ref('users');
    let query = await ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(useremail);
    try {
      await query.on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
          this.setState({friends: []});
          let friends = [];
          for (let k in child.val().friends) {
            friends.push(child.val().friends[k]);
          }
          if (this.state.isMounted) {
            this.setState({
              friends: friends,
              isLoading: false,
            });
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {}
  };
```

The problem is `componentWillUnmount()` is being called on render and shows the following warning:

> warning: can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component.

Comment: it would be easy if you can share your source code where this function called

Comment: Never never use isMounted inside state, isMounted for checking mount and unmount component for using and setting component state and wrong way to using isMounted inside component state. declare isMounted after component class before construction class and use it whole component where you are using async functions : this.isMounted

Comment: isMounted is an antipattern which facebook advises not to use https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @SDushan this function is called from componentdidmount

Comment: Removed but still getting the error.